# accurev: ignore all files with a given extension

Tags: accurev

I had assumed that placing a `*.classpath` entry in my .acignore file would ignore all filed that have the .classpath extension, but this only works for the root directory.  I can reach subdirectories using `*/*.classpath`, etc, but is there a blanket way to icnore all files in my project with that extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax to ignore the .classpath files recursively is:

**\*.classpath

Answer (score 3):

Recursive rules in the .acignore are not supported in AccuRev versions prior to 5.7. In version 5.6 and earlier, the ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS environment variable may be a better and less tedious solution.